# absolute java textbook example error

Tags: java, string

Can't figure out the small error I've made. This example is from the Absolute java textbook.

```
public class Display1_7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "I hate text processing!";
        int position = sentence.indexOf("hate");//finding the position of hate in variable sentence
        String ending = sentence.substring(position = "hate".length());/*cuts out the first half
                                                                        of the sentence*/

        System.out.println("0123456789");
        System.out.println(sentence);
        System.out.println("The word \"hate\" starts at index " 
                            + position);/*example of using quotes inside a string,
                                        also demonstrates concatenation of a variable*/

        sentence = sentence.substring(0, position) + "adore"+ ending;//I think I did this wrong?

        System.out.println("The changed string is:");
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }//end of main
 }
```

The expected output is

[image: here]

The output I get is [image: here]

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add the current and expected outputs.  Reference to links is highly discouraged especially for this simple example.

Comment: Also don't post text/code as image ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). If you want to format it simply use `code` section.

Comment: What do you expect from this line: `String ending = sentence.substring(position = "hate".length());` Why would you ever do this, even if this compiles? Didn't you want to use a comma there?

Comment: Yes Oleg, he's a beginner he doesn't know what to do that's the point.

Comment: I think the intention was for the assignment to `ending` to read `String ending = sentence.substring(position + "hate".length());` rather than the `=` typo you have there.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @ShadowGod So you are implying it is better to just give him the answer as others did rather than narrow down the problem and point out to where the problem is and let him do his thinking further? I am afraid this way he will remain a beginner...

Comment: Yeah it was a dumb typo. I'm using jcreator and that doesn't have a debugger, but I like it since it's simple.

Comment: @OlegSklyar I suppose we can do both. We can give him the answer and nicely explain what's wrong with what he did. If he really wants to learn he'll get it anyway. However I have to agree with you that I tend not to give answers to my students and rather try to have them think. But it's not really a classroom here. That's just my 2 cents on the question and I'm not saying I'm actually right by giving the answer.

Comment: It's the way you said it, you don't say "Why would you ever do this?", that's not helping, that's judging .. he does it that way because he *doesn't know how to do it*

Comment: @ShadowGod turns out we are wrong on that as he said it's just a typo. Still can't find the time to accept an answer though...

Answer (score 2):

You use an `=` instead of a `+` when you try to determine `ending`.

```
String ending = sentence.substring(position + "hate".length());
```

...should do the trick

Comment: Yep I submitted too late

Comment: Yeah well it happens :D.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that your  `String ending = sentence.substring(position ="hate".length());` should be  `String ending = sentence.substring(position +"hate".length());`
Indeed, the ending is the position of hate (returned by `IndexOf()`) to which you add the length of the word that you want to remove (in this case "hate").
The assignment you had in your code actually changed the value of position which switched from 2 to 4 (the length of hate). Thus, not only was the ending string wrong but your position was also wrong, making the final `String` exactly what you had.

So here is a corrected (and working) version of your code

```
public class Display1_7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "I hate text processing!";
        int position = sentence.indexOf("hate");//finding the position of hate in variable sentence
        String ending = sentence.substring(position +"hate".length());/*cuts out the first half
                                                                        of the sentence*/

        System.out.println("0123456789");
        System.out.println(sentence);
        System.out.println("The word \"hate\" starts at index " 
                            + position);/*example of using quotes inside a string,
                                        also demonstrates concatenation of a variable*/

        sentence = sentence.substring(0, position) + "adore"+ ending;

        System.out.println("The changed string is:");
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }
 }
```

Small note, I would avoid comments like "end of main", I mean there's just no point to them at all, anyone can understand that it was the end of main :). From what I gathered you're a beginner but still, this sort of comments just make useful comments fade away.